# Quickblox: how to delete user checkins within certain time period

Tags: ios, sdk, geolocation, quickblox

Does anyone know if it is possible to delete all user checkins within certain timeframe using QB iOS SDK?

There is a "mass delete" option available, but I do not want to delete all checkins including today's checkin but instead within certain time period in my app.

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-location_users-ios#Mass_delete

I know I could first mass delete all and then re-submit today's checkins (yes, may be more than one) but that would not be very efficient IMHO.

Any suggestions and comments appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it

```
QBLGeoDataDeleteRequest *deleteRequest = [[QBLGeoDataDeleteRequest alloc] init];
deleteRequest.days = 5;

[QBLocation deleteGeoDataWithRequest:deleteRequest delegate:self];
```

**days** - Maximum age of data that should remain in the database after a query.

Comment: Thanks @IgorKhomenko. So did I understand correctly, the parameter "days" actually means how many days of data will be kept in the database (counting backwards from this moment) and rest of the data will be removed? So to remove all check-ins except from today, the days parameter would be set as 1 (.days=1)? Fantastic, thanks a lot!